# Android OpenCV without GUI (open the camera module)

Tags: java, android, user-interface, opencv, camera

I have a camera running Android (API 19) without any display. I have installed OpenCV Manager in it and am now trying to get the camera images (to stream over the wifi). My problem is that the only way I have figured out to get the camera images with OpenCV is to create a JavaCameraView in the XML and add a CvCameraListener. But because there is no graphics in my hardware the app crashes if i set a content view. I have tried to create a new JavaCameraView:

```
camera = (CameraBridgeViewBase) new JavaCameraView(this, CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_ANY);
camera.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
camera.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
```

and enabling it (after that OpenCV has loaded correctly) but then I don't get any calls at all to the listener.

All i want is to have a function being called on every camera frame where I can extract the image data as a byte array. How can I do this without a Content View?